# Draw SubView in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, uiview, storyboard

I want to present a modalView (it can be a viewController) that I draw in Storyboard. I don't want to have to make the whole thing programmatically. Is there a way to do this without it being a full screen view?

I guess another way to ask the question is: how do I `[self.view addSubView:mySubView]` where `mySubView` is drawn in InterFaceBuilder/Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this properly, you should look at View Controller containment in the docs.  Basically you would `addChildViewController` after instantiating the viewController from your storyboard and then add the viewController's view to your current view hierarchy.

To just get it working however, the following will get you going:

```
UIViewController *childViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<identifier you set in Interface Builder>"];
[self.view addSubView:childViewController.view];
```

Note that one of the reasons to do it 'properly' will be to ensure that autorotation and presentation callbacks are sent to the sub view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Override the initWithCoder method in the object-c class.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
}
return self;
```

}